# aws autocaling ,application load balancer routing request to different endpoints of my application

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, aws-application-load-balancer

Aws AutoScaling, ALB, Different Endpoints of my application

I have implemented autoscaling in aws with ApplicationLoadBalancer(ALB). Everything works, i.e. when i paste my dns in browser it shows Nginx message.
I need help in how to send request to different endpoints of my django application using dns.
In normal case we generally have DomainName/IP address by using these we create a baseurl  and access different endpoints base_url/endpoint1/, base_url/endpoint2/ and so on.
How to do it using DNS. My application have both POST/GET request method type endpoints.

Comment: You can't. DNS Names only resolve to IP addresses. You can't use a path. You might be able to configure your web server to detect the domain name that was used and redirect to an alternate path. Search for "virtual host" for more information.